# fresh install of ember breaking on server start

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I have recently installed ember, version 1.13.14, node 4.1.1, npm 2.14.10, on windows 10 64 bit. I have completed the process of creating an app in ember, however, when I go to run the server using the command `ember s`, this error shows: `Cannot find module '....\bower_components\ember\ember-template-compiler'`. This is the full stack trace:

[image]

When I investigated further, by going into the `bower_components/ember` folder, I saw in `ember` the bower.json file was as such:

```
{
  "name": "ember",
  "version": "1.13.11",
  "main": [
    "./ember.debug.js",
    "./ember-template-compiler.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">= 1.7.0 < 2.2.0"
  }
}
```

However, only the bower.json in ember had both ember.debug.js and ember-template-compiler.js. the other files, listed as component.json, composer.json, and package.json only stated ember.debug.js

Is there a reason as to why this might be happening and what I can do to fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: you recently grabbed it (ember cli judging from window?) and it gave you that old version? It should have later versions.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed it myself! It turns out the version of ember was incorrect. I actually required ember 2.2.1 in order to proceed.